# Error en la implementación de cloudinary en express

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, rutas

Tengo un problema en la implementación de cloudinary y mi código en express, cuando intento establecer 'path' en el update de la imagen al servidor, me muestra que path (`solicitud.files.photo_image.path`) no está definida. La verdad es mi primera vez trabajando con la Api y no entiendo mucho porqué el error.

El error está in la línea 14:

```
 app.post('/photos', upload.any(), function(solicitud, respuesta){
  //console.log(solicitud.body);
  if(solicitud.body.password == "emmanuel_1234567"){
    var data = {
      title: solicitud.body.title,
      description: solicitud.body.description,
      imageUrl: 'images/carousel/1.jpg'
    };
    var fotos = new Fotos(data);

console.log(solicitud.files);

cloudinary.uploader.upload(
  solicitud.files.photo_image.path, function(result) {

    fotos.save(function(error){
      console.log('Datos de fotografía guardados satisfactoriamente:');
      console.log(fotos);
      respuesta.render('index');
    });

});


}else{
    respuesta.render('photos/new');
    console.log('Contraseña incorrecta, por favor, intentelo nuevamente...');
  }
```

Esto muestra en la terminal:

```
arleys-mbp:emmanuel_upegui arley_cuadrado$ node app.js 
Conexión establecida correctamente!!! :)
[ { fieldname: 'photo_image',
    originalname: 'esta.png',
    encoding: '7bit',
    mimetype: 'image/png',
    destination: './uploads',
    filename: 'ef11a117af617cac01d78d18e6cd2924',
    path: 'uploads/ef11a117af617cac01d78d18e6cd2924',
    size: 63050 } ]
TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined
```

Gracias anticipadas!

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que `solicitud.files` es un arreglo, no un objeto. De ahi que no tenga un atributo de nombre `photo_image`.

Puede resolverse cambiando la linea

```
cloudinary.uploader.upload(
  solicitud.files.photo_image.path, function(result) {
```

Por

```
cloudinary.uploader.upload(
  solicitud.files[0].path, function(result) {
```